# I'm getting a BSOD on Start-Up in Windows 10 but when I restart my computer, everything's okay?

Tags: windows, boot, windows-10, drivers, bsod

I've been delaying this because I haven't been altogether too fussed about it but it's becoming increasingly frustrating because my PC *should* (and does) boot up quickly. The problem is that ***every single time I boot it up, it bsods. I have to restart it in order for it to work.***

I've done the memcheck and the chkdsk. I've checked all of my drivers (Although I do believe it is a problem with a driver but I'm not sure about which one. Again, I'm probably wrong.) I **was** getting this problem in Windows 10 too. I've had it before I installed an extra drive and before I installed a new network card, so it's unlikely that those components are causing the problem. It might have something to do with the MOBO but I don't want to be too hasty.

When I do get the crash, it gives me a generic `DRIVER_POWER_FAILURE` without any other information.

I have checked the logs myself and nothing seems *too* out of the ordinary, but if anyone wants to take a look at the crash log, I'll be uploading it to my Google Drive. (It's around a gig in size.) I'll post the link when it finishes and then I'll bump my post.

If anyone could figure out the problem from the vague information I posted, or even any possible solutions, I would be more than happy to try it out!
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: share (onedrive) the dmp file from C:\windows\minidump.

Comment: Hey, thanks for letting me know about minidump! xD
Here's the link: https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArP1DLELB2aJjwdqhujfLJf1Y48O

Comment: ok, I posted what I see from the dmp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows uses a [new Boot since Windows 8 called Fast Startup](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/b8/2011/09/08/delivering-fast-boot-times-in-windows-8/), which is a logoff + hibernation to shutdown and a resume from hiberation + login at boot.

[image]

Here all drivers must support the hibernation/resume. you have an incompatible driver which causes the `DRIVER_POWER_FAILURE`. Here is the [Windbg output](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks):

```
    0: kd> !podev ffffe0012a433060
Device object is for:
  DriverObject 29674790
Current Irp 00000000 RefCount 0 Type 00000007 AttachedDev ffffe0012a42db20 DevFlags 00001050
Device queue is not busy.
Device Object Extension: ffffe0012a433bf0:
PowerFlags: 00000010 =>SystemState=0 DeviceState=1
Dope: 00000000:
0: kd> !devstack ffffe0012a42db20
  !DevObj           !DrvObj            !DevExt           ObjectName
  ffffe0012a4a9b10  \Driver\partmgr    ffffe0012a4a9c60  InfoMask field not found for _OBJECT_HEADER at ffffe0012a4a9ae0

  ffffe0012a4a9060  \Driver\disk       ffffe0012a4a91b0  InfoMask field not found for _OBJECT_HEADER at ffffe0012a4a9030

> ffffe0012a42db20 Unable to load image \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\amd_xata.sys, Win32 error 0n2
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for amd_xata.sys
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for amd_xata.sys
 \Driver\amd_xata   ffffe0012a42dc70  InfoMask field not found for _OBJECT_HEADER at ffffe0012a42daf0

  ffffe0012a433060  \Driver\amd_sata   ffffe0012a4331b0  Cannot read info offset from nt!ObpInfoMaskToOffset

!DevNode ffffe0012a353d30 :
  DeviceInst is "SCSI\Disk&Ven_SanDisk&Prod_SDSSDA120G\4&d21defa&0&020000"
  ServiceName is "disk"
0: kd> !irp ffffe0012a393b40
Irp is active with 7 stacks 5 is current (= 0xffffe0012a393d30)
 No Mdl: No System Buffer: Thread 00000000:  Irp stack trace.  
     cmd  flg cl Device   File     Completion-Context
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
 [IRP_MJ_POWER(16), IRP_MN_WAIT_WAKE(0)]
            0  0 ffffe0012a433060 00000000 fffff801ec729d50-ffffe0012a4a95a0    
           \Driver\amd_sata CLASSPNP!ClasspPowerUpCompletion
            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000002
>[IRP_MJ_POWER(16), IRP_MN_SET_POWER(2)]
            0 e1 ffffe0012a4a9060 00000000 fffff801eb9f3ae0-00000000 Success Error Cancel pending
           \Driver\disk partmgr!PmPowerCompletion
            Args: 00051100 00000001 00000001 00000002
 [IRP_MJ_POWER(16), IRP_MN_SET_POWER(2)]
            0 e1 ffffe0012a4a9b10 00000000 fffff801845100e8-ffffe0012a4a2f00 Success Error Cancel pending
           \Driver\partmgr  nt!PopRequestCompletion
            Args: 00051100 00000001 00000001 00000002
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-ffffe0012a4a2f00    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
0: kd> lmvm amd_sata
Browse full module list
start             end                 module name
fffff801`ebbd0000 fffff801`ebbed000   amd_sata T (no symbols)           
    Loaded symbol image file: amd_sata.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\amd_sata.sys
    Image name: amd_sata.sys
    Browse all global symbols  functions  data
    Timestamp:        Mon Jul 23 20:34:48 2012 (500D9948)
```

Here I can see that the Sandisk SSD (SCSI\Disk&Ven_SanDisk&Prod_SDSSDA120G) has issues and the related driver is the AMD SATA driver. [Download the latest driver from AMD](http://support.amd.com/de-de/download/chipset?os=Windows%2010%20-%2064) and install the driver to fix it because your driver is from 2012.

Comment: Many thanks! I think this did the trick.
I apologise for taking a while to accept your answer, but I wanted to try it today. Well, this is the first time it has booted and it hasn't crashed so far! AMD's driver update software is a bit broken as it said that I had already updated the driver to the newest version, but I updated _everything_ anyway and I'm typing this without any problems.

Comment: I've actually started to run into issues again even though I updated my CPU drivers so I decided to disable Fast-Startup. Doesn't really bother me that much, at all. I don't really notice a massive difference.